# How to update multiple record with check two column?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table name **students** with three column : id, name, status.

now I want to update every record 
where status= 'yes' if status=='no' AND status='no' if status=='yes'

**but I want it's in a single query using sql clauses.**

Comment: @user3663 need every record 'status' update with both situation means check on execution time if status=='no' then want status='yes' and status=='yes' then want status='no'.

Comment: okay you can try  scaisedge answer it will work

Comment: Any more possible status values than yes and no?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a a case when

```
update name_students
set status = case when status ='yes' then 'no'
                  when status = 'no' then 'yes'
              end
```

Comment: this i the sql code for mysql ...  you should simply use your php sql inteface for the right  coding

Comment: UPDATE student
    SET status =
        (CASE status 
             WHEN 'yes' THEN 'no' 
             WHEN 'no' THEN 'yes'             
         END)